# C++ C Loop Issue

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I have a problem with C/C++.
Below is actually my codes.
Once the menu is hit by an Option 1.
It runs and displays the results as per normal, re-displays the menu as well without fail.
However I will not be able to type anything afterwards.
Why is that so?
Thanks in advance to those who help, cheers!

*EDITTED, THIS IS MY WHOLE MAIN*

```
int main()
{
int Option;
Menu m;
do
{
    m.showMenu();
    cout<<"Please enter your choice:";
    cin>>Option;



    if (Option == 1)
    {

        int scenario = 0;
        string Lines;
        Mobile mobileObj;

        freopen("file.txt","r",stdin);


        while(true)
        {
            getline(cin,Lines);
            while(Lines.length() > 1 && Lines[0] == ' ') Lines = Lines.substr(1);
            if(Lines.length() == 1 && Lines[0] == ' ') continue;

            if(scenario == 0)
            {
                if(Lines == "Mobile Phones & Accessories Classifieds")
                {
                    scenario = 1;
                    getline(cin,Lines);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            else if(scenario == 1)
            {
                if(Lines[0] == '*') continue;
                else scenario = 2;
            }

            else if(scenario == 2)
            {
                if(Lines[0] == '[')
                {
                    for(unsigned int i=0;i<Lines.length();++i)
                    {
                        if(Lines[i] == ']')
                        {
                            mobileObj.mobDevName = Lines.substr(i+1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if(Lines.length() > 11 && is_number(Lines[0]) && is_number(Lines[1]) && is_number(Lines[10]))
                {
                    mobileObj.dateOfPub = Lines.substr(0,11);
                }

                else if(Lines.length() >= 5 && Lines[0] == 'S' && Lines[1] == '$')
                {
                    mobileObj.price = Lines;
                    v_Mob.push_back(mobileObj);
                }

                else if(Lines == "Browse Marketplace Listings") break;
            }

       }


    cout<<("[Mobile device Name] â€“ [Date of publish] â€“ [Mobile phonesâ€™ pricings]\n");

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<v_Mob.size();++i)
    {
        cout << i+1 << ") ";
        v_Mob[i].print();
    }

    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Going back to main menu ...\n";
    cout<<"\n";
}

else if (Option == 2)
    {
        cout<<"hi\n";
    }

}while(Option != 0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? We want to know, for instance, what the condition for ending the `do` loop is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first loop `stdin` is now the file "file.txt" due to:

```
freopen("file.txt","r",stdin);
```

So you cannot enter anything from the command prompt.

If you need to read from "file.txt" use a `ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream in("file.txt");
if (in.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(in, Lines))
    {
        // ...
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: use `fopen()` and get a new `FILE*`

Comment: hi hmjd, i have tried changing to ifstream, it hangs on me. i am not really sure why is it so.

Comment: @Andres, updated answer with terminating condition for `while` loop.

Comment: @hmjd, your solution works! however I have another question which, this option 1 will display 10 results. however, after each time i hit the option 1, it just increments the number of results with 10(the set of 10 results are the same). I wonder how could i solve it? Many thanks.

Comment: @Andres, you should ask another question for that. This question was about `stdin`.